# Set Log slf4j log level of Grails dependency

Tags: grails, logging

I have a dependency (OpenSAML) that is throwing an exception but has lots of slf4j logging built into the class (SAMLProtocolMessageXMLSignatureSecurityPolicyRule.class)

All of the logging is done at the debug level what is the best way to set the logging level to debug within a grails app?

Comment: Figured it out in Config.groovy add:
In the log4j section add:
debug 'org.opensaml.common.binding.security'

Answer (score 1):

In the Config.groovy Section add:
debug 'org.opensaml.common.binding.security'

For example
(org.opensaml.common.binding.security is of corse just the package name I want to set to debug)

```
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    debug 'org.opensaml.common.binding.security'
}
```